# XML Change during upgrade

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010

How do you change XML files usually during upgrade?? (Basic MSI)

I think "XML File Changes" Tab has too few function to change old app.config to new app.config. Because many kinds of old app.config have been deployed already, xml change should have enough function to cover all of them.

so, I am considering XSLT and XSLT Processor.

Do you think it is good for xml change?

if not, what can i do alternatively?

Answer (score 0):

When using a major upgrade the old version is automatically removed before installation starts. So old XML files are deleted and the new ones are installed.

There is no problem in upgrading XML files. You just need to make sure that the XML files in your new version have full functionality and don't rely on older versions.

Comment: for some reason, we are implementing major upgrade installer as a new installer. we should keep .config contents. any way to do this?

Comment: Major upgrades use new installers, so you are using the correct approach. If you want to keep the original config file you need backup and restore custom actions: backup the original file before upgrade and restore it when install is finished. InstallShield doesn't support this, so you will need to write your own custom actions.

Comment: so, how do you think about XSLT processor? the major version .config has a lot of change, so i think XML Changes in Basic MSI is not enough to change old config to new config